# Why is the actor "ask" pattern considered an anti-pattern or "code smell?"

Tags: scala, akka, actor

From what I've gathered, the "ask" pattern is considered a bad practice and should be avoided. Instead, the recommended pattern is the "actor per request" model. However, this doesn't make sense to me, as the "ask" pattern does exactly this - it creates a lightweight actor per request. So why is this then considered bad, especially when futures are far more composable and are able to more elegantly handle the collation of multiple send/receives?

Comment: Can you provide any reference to where this is recommended?  It's harder to make a case for/against something when one isn't quite sure what it is.  Also, such a reference might contain reasoning for why it's an anti-pattern that should be expanded or refuted.

Comment: I think I have come across something similar in the [Effective Akka](https://books.google.de/books?id=Wf5sAAAAQBAJ&pg=PP3&dq=Effective+Akka&hl=de&sa=X&ei=lGn3VM_CHKPlywPf5IDwAw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Effective%20Akka&f=false) book by Jamie Allen, see chapter 2 section *The Extra Pattern* and sub-sections *The Problem* and *Avoiding Ask*.

The reasoning seems to be that `ask` uses unnecessary resources, since a `PromiseActorRef` is created behind the scenes per `ask` call. The example in the book uses multiple `ask`s and optimizes that into a single *per-request actor*.

Comment: Part of the problem is that if you are asking from one actor to another, and get a future back, you could end up closing over mutable state when processing that Future callback.  By avoiding ask, and thus Futures, you eliminate these situations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From Akka [docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html):

> "There are performance implications of using ask since something needs
>   to keep track of when it times out, there needs to be something that
>   bridges a Promise into an ActorRef and it also needs to be reachable
>   through remoting. So always prefer tell for performance, and only ask
>   if you must."

But sometimes you want to send a message from outside of an actor in which case you can use `ask`. Using `ask` will guarantee that you get a response within the specified timeout and sometimes that's what you want. However, when you use `ask` pattern you should ask yourself a question whether you could just use `Future`s instead.

There is a place for `ask` but it should have very limited use due to the aforementioned reasons.

You don't have to use actor per request. Some actors are meant to be long lived and some not. If an actor performs a potentially dangerous or blocking operation you might want to create one per request. Whatever fits your application logic.